# Webpack 4 bundle splitting, sharing scope between bundles

Tags: webpack, vue.js, webpack-4, code-splitting, vuex-modules

We have recently split our main app.js bundle into many small bundles (small apps) via multiple entry points (functionality that comes out of the box with webpack 4)

Each bundle has different vue components inside and they import the vuex store which has all the modules. Before splitting the bundles - this store was a singleton and shared between all the components, i.e. - when one component mutated the store - the others would reflect the change.

Now that we have many bundles importing the store - it seems like they don't share the scope and each bundle has it's own store. Is there any way around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be related to this solved issue `Every entry point has their own module cache (webpack 4) instead of a shared module cache (webpack 3)` https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/7556#issuecomment-398523835